# How can I prevent Cross Site Scripting vulnerability when using Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)?

Tags: c#, xss

Is there any way to prevent xss attacks on content disposition for downloading excel file in C#?

I'm using Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment), to pop a file dialog for users when they download excel file to their local machines.
But scan results stated that this Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment) has Stored XSS vulnerability.

Below is the code that has vulnerability detected

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + myfile.Name + "\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.TransmitFile(myfile.FullName);
```

Comment: What has detected the vulnerability, and what precisely is it saying the vulnerability is?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide more context around the question. Please also edit the title to be more descriptive and less like a series of keywords crammed together.

Comment: Hi. I have edited and revised the question. Please let me know if it's not clear enough. Thanks